# call method against every item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

Imagine I have this type:

```
function Greeter(greeting) {
     this.greeting = greeting;
}
Greeter.prototype.say = function(audience) { 
    audience = audience || "world";
    console.log(this.gretting, audience);
};
```

And an array like this:

```
var greeters = [new Greeter("hello"), new Greeter("bonjour")];
```

Is there some way to do something like this:

```
greeters.onEach("say", "people");
// outputs:
// hello people
// bonjour people
```

Of course that method is imaginary, but it feels like there should be some clever way to do it without defining a new method on the `Array` prototype, perhaps by using call/apply on `forEach`/`map`/something else?

If you're interested, here's a naive implementation of the above `onEach` method:

```
Array.prototype.onEach= function(func) { 
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); 
    this.forEach(function(item) { 
        item[func].apply(item, args); 
    });
};
```

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#forEach

Comment: @SLaks that's just a shim for `Array.prototype.forEach` - the OP wants something that invokes a specific *named* function on each object, not a single supplied function reference.

Comment: @Alnitak exactly! It doesn't do what I ask, and I've already shown how  forEach can be used to achieve it anyway

Comment: @WickyNilliams FWIW, I can't think of anything easier than what you already wrote, which is kinda neat.  However for safety's sake you should use `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'onEach', ...)` where available so that the new method doesn't appear as an enumerable property of every `Array` object.

Comment: the code you have is the code you want. You might want to first make sure that function even exists, but other than that, you already have your answer.

Comment: @Alnitak @Mike I was hoping (as with most things in JS) there's some clever way to do it that is probably terrible in actual code, but good for gaining a deeper understanding of JS. I did say the implementation was naive, just hoping it would help people understand what i was asking (evidently not judging by the answers!). Though thanks for the tip on `defineProperty`, very good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought I think the best way to achieve this is with a helper function. This saves polluting the Array prototype and still gives a terse approach to this problem. It's very similar to my above `onEach` method but uses a closure to create a function that can be used as the iterator.

```
function func(name) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[name] && obj[name].apply(obj, args);
  }
}
```

This could then be used against my array above like this:

```
greeters.forEach(func("say")); // call function "say" on each object
greeters.map(func("say", "people")); // ["hello people", "bonjour people"]
```

I suspect this would also be considered a "more functional" approach to the problem. Over a large code base this can probably save a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

you could try somthing like this:

```
greeters.forEach(function(greeter){
   greeter.say('people');
});
```

Comment: although this doesn't strictly answer the OP's question, there's something to be said for just using a simple method like this with `forEach` instead of creating a new helper function.